# Really love aviation but have a computer science degree. What kind of jobs could I possibly get which involve aviation?

Tags: career

I really want to work in the aviation industry. Is there any way I can put my computer science degree to use in this industry.

Comment: Avionics? Can you provide more detail on your aspirations?

Comment: Don't forget ATC hardware and software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/which-companies-develop-software-for-airplane-systems?rq=1

Comment: Computer science covers a lot of different things. What are we talking about here? Algorithmics? Networks? HCI? Database management? Cybersecurity?

Comment: Me too! But 15 years in the software industry and I'd love to work in Aviation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because careers advice is too specific to the individual asking for that advice to be of general interest.

Comment: This would really be a better topic for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) than the site...

Comment: If you want to work on something that's actually on-board the airplane, I'd recommend getting as much embedded development experience as you can.

Comment: reirab is right. For that you want 2 languages, Assembly and C. Every processor has it's own version of assembly these days, but they are mostly very similar. I'm told most of them run compiled C too. Assembly is the starting point but a lot of CS folks these days have trouble with it because it's so low-level, just one step above machine code. I don't know your situation so I'll just leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this question comes within the scope of this site the way it is phrased.

Anyway, Aviation industry is highly interdisciplinary and has a lot of scope for computer science engineers like,

- Design of aircraft subsystems
- Development of programs for design and analysis of aircraft components (CAD, CFD etc).
- Instrumentation and testing of aircraft systems
- Development of aircraft control systems (e.g fly by wire)
- Aircraft testing and telemetry.
- Aircraft maintenance, which is becoming software intensive.
- Software for Airborne (avionics) and Ground based systems (e.g. Air traffic Management).
- Development of aircraft display systems.
- Software for communication systems for UAVs.

This list is by no means exhaustive. In most parts of aviation, there is a requirement for computer science engineers.

Comment: Not to mention the admin side of things, even if you're not directly working on the software that makes the aircraft fly. Revenue Integrity, route planning etc - airlines churn through a **huge** amount of data. I was amazed when I worked in Airline Revenue Integrity just how much data they crunch daily, even at smaller airlines.